# google-drive-sdk export Daily Limit unauthenticated use

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to download/export a file according to the [v3 example published by google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads).  I am getting the "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." error.

I have searched here and elsewhere and all of the links suggest I am missing setting up the credentials.  However, I am building on top of the basic [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and am able to list out the contents of my drive folder in this same application.  And yes, I have changed the requested scope from drive.metadata.readonly to drive.readonly to support downloading.  What am I missing?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Drive v3 API to list first 10 items (this works)
# example from google.
results = drive_service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

# Try to download the first item (it's a google doc I can edit, this FAILS)
# code pretty much lifted from google
file_id = items[0]['id']
print (file_id)
request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                             mimeType='application/pdf')
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print ( "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The example from Google was caching the credentials file (credentials.json).  When I originally ran the example the scoped permissions were not for drive.readonly, but for drive.metadata.readonly. I think when I changed them the request was not longer valid.

I deleted and credentials.json and re-ran the script (and re-approved the credentials request on my browser) and it was successful. I also ended up using the following to store the data as the BytesIO wasn't actually writing to disk.

```
data = drive_service.files().export(fileId=file_id,
                                       mimeType='application/pdf').execute()
f = open('MyFile.pdf','wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```